# How to Disable Kernel module installation capability in Unix Based operating system?

Tags: linux-kernel, security, kernel-modules

As we are living in the Linux kernel rootkit era, Is there any way to Disable any additional module to load into operating system kernel by any user or any operation or command , in Linux? some sort of locking down the kernel space.

PS :

I know we can remove any compiler tools and some hardening, but i am looking for additional protection in Kernel space and critical files and directory in its use.

I know we could remove **insmod** tool in **/sbin/insmod**, but somebody could recopy it to OS and use it again.

Comment: You used the word "Linux" once in your question, but the word "UNIX" twice. Are you interested, in this question, about only the Linux OS? Or others, including IRIX, HP-UX, AIX, Solaris, etc?

Comment: It's been log since my last login because nobody answered it for a long time and I assumed that there is no way, and thank you for commenting and editing the question, and yes, locking down Linux was my main question and beacuse most referenced article I found was using UNIX Base System phrase, so I guessed it would be a right word !

Answer (score 5):

There are several things you could do:

### Block kernel module loading until the system is rebooted

Simply run `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/modules_disabled`

After this, no new modules can be loaded for as long as the kernel is running. This setting cannot be reset back to 0 without rebooting.

This still allows loading modules at boot time, but allows you to lock it down once all the necessary modules have been loaded.

### Ensure that only trustworthy modules can be loaded in the first place

These methods will allow you to have your cake and eat it too:

If your system has UEFI firmware and Secure Boot is enabled, it is actually a Secure Boot certification requirement that the bootloader must not allow unsigned kernel code to be executed. Most distributions that support Secure Boot will extend this to kernel modules too, using kernel module signing (kernel compile options `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y` and `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE=y`).

Or, if you compile your own kernel, you could enable the `CONFIG_SECURITY_LOADPIN` kernel compilation option, which adds a requirement that all kernel modules must come from a single filesystem. This could be useful if you've segregated all user-writeable and temporary directories to separate filesystems, or even have your root filesystem read-only in locked-down use.

And of course, there is the hard-core option...

### Build your own custom kernel with all the necessary drivers built-in and the module functionality entirely disabled

This is old-school, but can still be applicable if your hardware configuration is very stable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , but as i understand, there is no way to disable it permanently in the running server.

Comment: @comeymacdonald did you try the modules_disabled method? If you set that value at boot-time, it seems to me that would be pretty effective. Also, disabling module support in the kernel sounds like a "permanent disablement " to me as well. How do you see these differently?

Answer (score -1):

you can not be disabling completely the "modules_disabled" - LKM.
Actually, you can disable it, but if some user has root access to the machine, this magic will be unusable. The decision is that: You must compiling your own Linux Kernel project and you should completely disabled "modules_disabled" from "Enable loadable modules to support" menu. `https://github.com/nu11secur1ty/Linux_hardening_and_security/tree/master/Kernel-sec-modules_by_nu11secur1ty/linux-5.1.1/kernel` BR